# Error occured when i use webapi to get data on umbraco

Tags: asp.net-web-api, umbraco, umbraco7

I am using Umbraco 7.4.0. When I installed Umbraco Forms 4.2.1 in my project that working fine.when i was proceeding a project, i need to use webapi to get user registration info, but i can't receive data from webapi on Umbraco. 
But if i copy code to another page outside Umbraco, 
i can receive that data from webapi. [Here is the partial](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Lf0jX.png)

I tried to revise the script, deleted some useless script, but the problem is still there.
I want to know why is it like this? Am I missing something?
Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

It's a bit hard to answer your question without more information on what you are trying to do.

You should however note that if you just copy a controller class from a normal ASP.NET project into a Umbraco solution it will not "just work".

Controllers routes needs to be registrered for controller actions to be hit. This usually happens by auto-routing on `/controller/action/id` URLs in your site for MVC and `/api/controller/id` for WebAPI controllers.

This auto-routing is not enabled by default in a Umbraco site so you would have to manually do something similar to what happens in the `RouteConfig.cs` / `WebApiConfig.cs` to route controllers and be able to reach them.

You should however also look into using the `UmbracoApiController` which will most likely be the easiest solution for you. If you make your controller inherit from this, it will get auto-routed by Umbraco on a `/Umbraco/Api/[YourControllerName]` URL and you should be able to reach it. The cool thing about using the `UmbracoApiController` is that it is just the same as a normal WebAPI controller, with the added benefit of being able to reach the Umbraco context/services.

You can see documentation on the webapi/routing stuff here:
https://our.umbraco.org/documentation/reference/routing/webapi/